# SQL Server 2008 - Error Order by case

Tags: sql-server-2008, rollup

I'm getting the following error messages:

Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'customers.member_category' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.

How can I order the results by the case?

Thanks

```
SELECT
Date,
order_id,
member_category,
COUNT(*) AS no_items, 
SUM(item_amount) AS total_amount
FROM 
order_items OI (NOLOCK) JOIN customers C (NOLOCK) 
ON OI.CUSTOMER_NO = C.CUSTOMER_NO
WHERE 
DATE = '01 FEB 2014'
GROUP BY 
order_id, 
member_category
UNION
SELECT
    '',
    '',
'Total',
COUNT(*) AS no_items, 
SUM(item_amount) AS total_amount
FROM 
order_items OI (NOLOCK) JOIN customers C (NOLOCK) 
ON OI.CUSTOMER_NO = C.CUSTOMER_NO
WHERE 
DATE = '01 FEB 2014'
GROUP BY Date WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY Date ASC, CASE member_category WHEN 'VIP' THEN 1
                    WHEN 'STD' THEN 2                   
                    WHEN 'GLD' THEN 3 
           END
```

Comment: You are missing `SELECT` after your `UNION`. You should probably use `UNION ALL` (understand the difference). With regards to the error you posted, you need to follow it's instruction - add the column to the select list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second part of your `UNION` statement does not contain field `member_category`. This violates basic principle of `UNION` which is that number and order of columns in each statement should be same.

To resolve the issue, you need to add `member_category` both in the list of retrieved columns and in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: But I don't want to subtotal by member_category. Is there any other way around it?

Comment: How about getting rid of the `union` altogether and directly adding `ROLLUP` to your first query? You can refer to this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: It was much easier with compute. Why did they have to take it away!